# Using brackets to select html elements in CSS doesn't select first element

Tags: html, css

### can´t select properly elements in HTML with CSS

### context

- i'm learning front-end and I did this test page for a test

### what I did already.

- In the root folder a `test.html` I wrote this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/csstest.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p> text number one</p>
    <p class="test_class"> text number two</p>
</body>
</html>
```

- Then I made a folder called `css` and inside a `csstest.css` file

```
p [class = "test_class"] {color: red;}
```

#### What I was trying to achieve, and what I tried.

- I Was trying to select "text number two" text and display it in red.
- It DID work if I put a span element in between paragraphs like this.

```
<p><span class="test_class"> prueba numero dos</span></p>
```

Comment: (Some) spaces are significant in CSS – get rid of the space between `p` and `[class ...]` and it should work.

Comment: For what it's worth – the shorter / better / more common way to do this is to use CSS dot notation. That is, `p.test_class { color: red }`

Comment: U can use just  .test_class{...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, its more easier if you use class selector instead of attribute selector. Like this:

```css
  p.test_class {color: red;}
```

But if you still want to use attribute selector be carefull with whitespaces, because space is descendant selector (see more information here: [descendant selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)):

```
  p[class = "test_class"] {color:red;}
```

A usefull doc for css selectors: [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)